# MS Access - Hide Columns on Subform

Tags: ms-access

I have a nagging issue today -

Task:

1. I have a subform on a form, based on a query
2. When I open the form I want to hide a subset of columns by default
3. I created a Public function for this: hideRawCols()

Issue:

1. Using the subform's OnLoad or OnOpen events, the subform is ignoring the function, columns are not hidden when form/subform is painted
2. I have an Option toggle on the form that calls this same function, and it works just fine. [(1) = Show, (2) Hide], Default value (2)

Example:

```
Public Function hideRawCols()

If Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]!frmRaw.Value = 2 Then
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Item").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Desc").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Mfg").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Mfgid").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Area").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Depart").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Pack").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Uom").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Cost").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
Else
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Item").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Desc").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Mfg").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Mfgid").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Area").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Depart").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Pack").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Uom").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
    Forms![2_4_6 QA Review]![2_4_6 QA Review subform].Form.Controls("Raw_Cost").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
End If


End Function
```

My intuition tells me its a timing issue Loading or Opening the form/subform.  Are there any events I can use once the form is fully painted.  A small blink woulf be acceptable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice:  Calling the function from the Parent Form's OnLoad event seems  to produce the desired results.